# What can I invest in with my excess of Caps?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

After a few [lucky nights gambling](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/The_Courier_Who_Broke_the_Bank) on the Strip, a successful raid on [a mysterious vault](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Sierra_Madre_vault), and a smattering of [snow globes](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Snow_globe) my Courier has acquired an excess of 100,000 bottle caps. Now that I have all of this money what can I do with it?

I had spent a few thousand caps on [implants](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_implants) to upgrade my character, as well as purchasing all of the upgrades in the [Lucky 38 Presidential Suite](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Lucky_38_presidential_suite) but I still have more caps than I know how to spend. Weapons, especially from the [Gun Runners Arsenal](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Gun_Runners%27_Arsenal), seem like a decent investment but most of them will end up stored in a box somewhere because I don't need that many, especially after purchasing [Medicine Stick](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Medicine_Stick_(GRA)).

Are there any other money sinks in the Mojave that I can upgrade? I'd prefer purchases that offer permanent upgrades rather than buying weapons, equipment, or consumables - things I can scavenge on my own.

This question can be extended to purchases in any of the game's DLC.

Comment: To the VTC'er: I don't see how this is opinion-based - PausePause is clearly asking for possibilities, not which one of those meets a certain requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Thorn out by Westside, you can set up custom fights for a few hundred caps.
Also, if you are looking for good weapons you can bet caps on, I would suggest looking for custom weapons and modding them. For example, the Ratslayer is a fully modded varmin rifle in the broc flower cave.

Comment: It's worth noting that unique weapons cannot be upgraded with weapon mods. The Thorn is a good way to spend caps, but it's more gambling than it is an investment.